# i18n URL format with language parameter always in URL

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, internationalization, seo

I'm working on a new website and I have a question regarding internalization (i18n) and SEO.

Here's the case. I'm using this CodeIgniter [code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) to translate my website in 2 languages.
Let's say these languages are English and Dutch.

When using this code, people visiting mydomain.com are redirected to mydomain.com/en/defaultcontrollername
where English is the default language.

I will have a simple selectbox where users can switch to Dutch. The url will then be the same, except "en" is replaced with "nl".

Now my question is: is it bad practice in terms of SEO that the default language is always present in the URL? Also, does an immediate redirect to mydomain.com/en/defaultcontrollername after opening mydomain.com have effect on SEO?

Is it better to always use a default language and present that first, or to "guess" the language based on browser headers?

Last but not least: do I also have to translate my controller names.

Comment: So what do u want exactly?...I mean you always need that 'en' and 'nl' say language identifier in your Url or not?

Comment: This particular piece of CodeIgniter always supplies the language parameter in the URL. I'm not sure if that is the best approach though.

Comment: OKay...thats Not at all necessary to supply languageparameter even single time....I have Made One website recently supporting four Language without language in url....What can you do is store your default langugae say 'en' in cookie and map language file for en and load content from der...if user change the langage then replace the value in cookie by new langage and map it to the path of your langage file same as value in cookie...so you don't need to change Url

Comment: I know you can use cookies and sessions. But that seems really bad for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [How should I structure my urls for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44289/14543)

Having a folder (or subdomain, or top level domain) with the language is the preferred setup for optimal SEO.

You can translate words in the URL itself (the controller name in your case).

- It makes the URLs look more appealing to non-English users.
- Any non-ASCII characters have to be URL encoded (UTF-8).
- URLS can get very long with even a few international characters.
- Browsers often show URLs not encoded in the URL bar but they get copied and pasted encoded.

Comment: So it is OK to ALWAYS have the language in the URL, even for the default language? thanks

Comment: Yes, it is fine even for the default language.  Wikipedia does that.